# SRV record not working properly?

Tags: cname-record, ddns, srv-record

I'm currently dealing with a little problem that routes back to me simply not having a static IP, as my ISP charges a ridiculous sum for that.

I have a DDNS in place, which works fine. Except, I'm now trying to provide a service under a subdomain.

The current, non-functional, solution is to simply set up a CNAME Record and additionally an SRV Record:

```
example.example.com       IN CNAME example.com
_example._tcp.example.com IN SRV   Port 1111 example.example.com
```

It didn't make much sense to me but some users reported having success this way and other prior solutions didn't work nonetheless. But instead, `example.example.com` is a dead end, while `example.com` results in `example.com:1111`.

I'm completely stumped at this point. All I intend to have is a subdomain directing to my actual IP on port 1111. Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: When you added your records, did you try to query them? Like `host -t srv _example._tcp.example.com` and so on.

Comment: Do the clients of the service you're hosting actually utilize SRV records to locate the service in question? This sounds suspiciously like you trying to use SRV records to host a website or other HTTP based service on a non-default port. But web browsers don't understand SRV records and you can't use them to do that.

Comment: @Nikita Kipriyanoc it's a graphical UI, cpanel to be precise. So no.

Comment: @Ryan Bolger  Kind of. And i suspected that too. Although, it's not a webpage or anything, it's part of an API. The federation API to be precise, I'm trying to get a synapse server going. But I have my doubts as it does kinda work apparently according to the federation tester. When typing in the subdomain its a dead end, but typing in my regular op-level domain it actually connects to my server on the intended port. I can't explain why or how, normally that would mean that my other services shouldn't be reachable anymore, but they are, despite the domain currently pointing to this port always

Comment: I hadn't asked you *how* you added these records. It doesn't matter. I asked you *to check* after you added them. You can use any tool for that, I gave an example how to check with `host` utility from ISC BIND, but there are many others, `nslookup`, `dig` and plenty of online looking glasses in the Internet. And I'll save my option to send you away to CPanel helpdesk to some later time.

Comment: Oh sorry, now i got what you meant. I just checked on websites like dns.pexip.com or dnslookup.online. The results for those turned out negative aswell i'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

I think you’re missing a couple of `.`s. Try:

```
example.example.com. IN CNAME example.com.
```

Comment: I don't believe so, I checked and while the dots were missing, cpanel would just remove them as soon as I hit enter